# GNU Parallel with Python Script - command line variables not working

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, gnu-parallel

This is the first time I am trying to do python execution in GNU parallel.

I have the below python script.  I am trying to run it in parallel with a text.txt document loading the variables.  The text document has the variables one on each line.

I execute the below script with this code:
`parallel --bar -a PairNames.txt python3 CreateDataTablePythonScriptv2.py`

Here is the python script being executed:

```
import sqlite3
import sys

PairName = sys.argv[1]
print(PairName)
DTBLocation = '//mnt//c//Users//Jonathan//OneDrive - Mazars in Oman//Trading//Systems//FibMatrix//Testing Trade Analysis//SQLite//Trade Analysis.db
connection = sqlite3.connect(DTBLocation)
cursor = connection.cursor()

TableName = PairName+'_DATA'
print(TableName)
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}
(
    Date_Time INTEGER,
    Open REAL,
    Max_60m_Box REAL

 )""".format(TableName))
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

It executes correctly the first variable just fine.  But the remainder of the variables do print correctly from the print command for the PairName, but for print(TableName) I get the below displays:

```
GBPUSD
_DATAD

USDCHF
_DATAF

NZDJPY
_DATAY
```

Its weird to me that it prints the PairName just fine and correctly, but then the PairName does not show up when concating the TableName.

Also, its weird that an extra letter gets added to the end of DATA for each one.  It appears that the extra letter at the end of the DATA is the last letter of the input variable.  I don't know why its choping the 5 letters off and how it puts it at the end of the DATA.

I printed the tablename.
I watched this video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ&ab_channel=OleTange[^]
I tried moving the TableName concat to right under the PairName
I printed the type of the PairName, and it is a string
I tried seperating the varibales in the txt document by tabs and commas instead of next line

I tried assigning the "_DATA" to a variable and then concating the two objects.  But it had same result:
TableEnd = '_DATA'
TableName = PairName + TableEnd

If I remove the concat of PairName+'_DATA' and just use PairName only as the TableName, then it works correctly.

Sorry if this is a simple answer, but I cannot figure it out and especially since there is not too much documentation / tutorials for a newbie on GNU Parallel in this situation.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Read chapter 1+2 https://zenodo.org/record/1146014. Especially 2.2 seems relevant here: What is GNU Parallel actually executing? (`--dryrun`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input file is not in DOS format (i.e. ends in a CRLF rather than just an LF)? I checked this using the FILE command:

```
$ file test.txt 
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$
```

Since it was CRLF (DOS format), I converted it using tr:

````
Copy Codetr -d '\r' < input.file > output.file```
````